# Newb issue with wget sftp - hangs on authentication

Tags: bash, sftp

I am a web dev trying to do a little bit of Linux admin and could use help. My server needs to retrieve a file daily from a remote location over sftp, name and date/time stamp it, and push it to a directory for archive.

I have adapted a shell script that I had working when doing this over ftp, but sftp is causing me some issues.

I can successfully connect to the server in Filezilla when I have it set to the sftp protocol and choose the "Longon Type" as "Interactive" where it prompts for a password.

When I use the command line to call my script, it seems to resolve but hangs on the logging in step and provides the following error before retrying: "Error in server response, closing control connection. Retrying."

Here is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td67w.png

This is the contents of my script where I've replaced any sensitive information with a placeholder in ALL CAPS.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script Function:
# This bash script backups up the .csv everyday (dependent on cron job run) with a file name time stamp.

#[Changes Directory]
cd /THEDIRECTORY

wget --no-passive-ftp --output-document=completed`date +%Y-%m-%d`.csv --user=THEUSER --password='THEPASSWORD' ftp://sftp.THEDOMAIN.com:22 completed.csv
```

Anyone wanna help a newb to get some of them internet points?! :-)

Comment: Why is this tagged `bash`?

Comment: I would use `expect` to do what you need.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687754/bash-script-send-files-to-sftp-using-expect or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724845/sftp-using-expect

Comment: Thank you, @GoinOff.  That put me on the right path.  I'm now using expect to do this and it works great!

Comment: Glad it's working for you DJ..`expect` is an awesome tool.  I use it with `sftp` to transfer files from remote servers.